# Error C2143 and C4430 in class definition;

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, syntax-error

I've got a problem.
When I declare pointer on class World in class Organism I gets `C2143` and `C4430` errors. When I comment this line all of these errors disappears...
I don't know how to declare the reference to class World. Help! Guide me, where I can find the solution.

```
1>  Touching "Debug\Gra.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>g:\projekt\gra\gra\organism.h(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>g:\projekt\gra\gra\organism.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>g:\projekt\gra\gra\organism.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  World.cpp
1>g:\projekt\gra\gra\organism.h(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>g:\projekt\gra\gra\organism.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>g:\projekt\gra\gra\organism.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  Human.cpp
1>g:\projekt\gra\gra\plant.h(5): error C2504: 'Organism' : base class undefined
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  Plant.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

**file World.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "Plant.h"

class World {    
public:
    World(int x = 15, int y = 15);
    ~World();
    void nextTurn(); // next turn
    void printWorld(); // print world in ASCII
    void printStats(); // print descripction about obejcts in the world
    friend class Organism;

protected:
    int x, y; // size of the world
    int orgCnt; // organism counter
    Organism **coord; // coordinates of the world
    int round; // equivalent of time in the world;
};
```

**file Organism.h:**

```
#pragma once    
#include "World.h"

class Organism {
public:
    virtual bool action() = 0;
    virtual void move() = 0;
    virtual bool collision() = 0;   
    virtual void show() = 0;
    virtual void insert() = 0;

protected:
    World *w; //---error here--- When i comment this line, everyting is ok.
    int power;
    int activity;
    int x, y;
};
```

file Human.h

```
#pragma once    
#include "Organism.h"

class Human: public Organism {    
public:
    Human();
    ~Human();
    virtual bool action();
    virtual bool collision();
    virtual void move();
    virtual void show();
    virtual void insert();
};
```

Comment: In the shown source, where do the errors occur? There's not a missing semicolon (or other error) in the `plant.h` header file (errors in header files can manifest in the files they are included in).?

Comment: No, in these files(main.cpp, World.cpp, Human.cpp) I think that everything is okay, because if I comment featured line, the problem doesn't occur... But I look there one more time...

Comment: You certainly don't need `extern` on `extern class World;`, and it's hard to believe you need any of it if the .h files are really as posted here.

Comment: @Mateusz please do not edit answers into the question. Instead, post an Answer .